# creating sequence in a list in R

Tags: r, list, seq

Im interested in generating a list with a sequencing of numbers like in this fashion:

```
list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9)
```

I have tried variations of using list and seq without luck and using repetition like rep(list(1:3), 3) gets me the right format but without the advancing sequencing so I'm at a loss to what probably is a really simple problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't clear. What is wrong with `list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9)`? Presumably there is a more general problem you are trying to solve, but if so what is it?

Comment: Sorry I should have added im trying to create a list from a long sequence of numbers, for arguments sake 1:300. so 1:3 in list[1], 4:6 in List[2] etc

Comment: Try `my_list <- c(list(1:3), list(4:6), list(7:9))` then.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solved my issue

Comment: The provided question is sufficient to achieve your goal. But I leave the following for you. `x <- 1:9; y <- seq(from = 1, to = 9, by = 3); split(x, f = findInterval(x = x, vec = y))`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gl` to create a grouping variable for `split`ting the `vector`

```
split(x, as.integer(gl(length(x), 3, length(x))))
```

#### data

```
x <- 1:9
```